# Use menu <li> link or onClick to set a variable

Tags: php, functions, javascript

I built a menu for a page that displays array data by week and day. The menu is laid out with links for Day-1 | Day-2 | Day-3 ... thru Day-7. I then have a variable $day_number that I use to select a day row from an array to display content on the page. I can change the day displayed on the page manually by changing the $day_number value. I want to set up the menu to update the variable on click.

I was able to set up onClick function calls for each menu item, but then I have the problem of setting the variable $day_number outside of the function. Since I am calling the function from the  I can't use the return result.

Here is the current menu structure. I am open to another option other than using the onClick function call.

```
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li class="dayLink" id="day_1"><a href="#" onClick="setDay('Day1');">Day 1</a></li>
    <li class="dayLink" id="day_2"><a href="#" onClick="setDay('Day2');">Day 2</a></li>
    <li class="dayLink" id="day_3"><a href="#" onClick="setDay('Day3');">Day 3</a></li>
    <li class="dayLink" id="day_4"><a href="#" onClick="setDay('Day4');">Day 4</a></li>
    <li class="dayLink" id="day_5"><a href="#" onClick="setDay('Day5');">Day 5</a></li>
    <li class="dayLink" id="day_6"><a href="#" onClick="setDay('Day6');">Day 6</a></li>
    <li class="dayLink" id="day_7"><a href="#" onClick="setDay('Day7');">Day 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the function run by the onClick. It passes the setDay value so I know what day link was clicked. This works fine but I need to have the click event set the value for $day_number outside the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setDay($day)
{
    console.log($day);
}
</script>
```

Comment: instead adding on click directly in code use id of li to get the same value you are passing in setDay.


`jQuery('.dayLink a').click(function()
{

   console.log(jQuery(this).closest('.dayLink').attr('id'));

})`

Comment: This is what I was originally trying to do but having trouble getting the template script to recognize jQuery. It is supposed to be part of WordPress, but when I add the necessary opening statement (jQuery(document).ready(function($){) it still does not work.

Comment: You can add this in template.php

Comment: I tried it in the template before and it did not work. On closer inspection the closing brackets are out of order. It now works. Question: How do I assign the var li_id to a php variable outside of the jQuery script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this you can pass the value using ajax, you have fetch value from $_POST in your php script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.dayLink a').click(function(){
     var li_id = jQuery(this).closest('.dayLink').attr('id');
     jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'url_to_php_script',
        data: {dayValue: li_id,action:call_to_ajax},
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(res){
            console.log(res);
        }
     })
  });
});
```

The closing brackets were out of order.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['li_id'])){
    $test = $_GET['li_id'];
    echo $test;
    }
?>
```

New php script added to echo the value passed with the POST method.

Below is the entire script in the php file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.dayLink a').click(function(){
  var li_id = jQuery(this).closest('.dayLink').attr('id');
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'https://grat-itudefitness/wp-content/themes/divi-child-gratitudefitness/includes/b2p_program_navigation.php',
    data: {dayValue: li_id},
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(res){
      console.log(res);
      }
    })
  });
});
</script>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['li_id'])){
  $test = $_GET['li_id'];
  echo $test;
  }
?>

<!-- Exercise Menu -->
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li class="dayLink" id="day_1"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Day 1</a></li>
  <li class="dayLink" id="day_2"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Day 2</a></li>       
  <li class="dayLink" id="day_3"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Day 3</a></li>
  <li class="dayLink" id="day_4"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Day 4</a></li>
  <li class="dayLink" id="day_5"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Day 5</a></li>
  <li class="dayLink" id="day_6"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Day 6</a></li>
  <li class="dayLink" id="day_7"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Day 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

The code you need::

** Code to keep in template file **

```
<?php
  $actionName = 'callMyAjax';
  $nonce = wp_create_nonce($actionName);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.dayLink a').click(function(){
  var li_id = jQuery(this).closest('.dayLink').attr('id');
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: {dayValue: li_id,action:<?php echo $actionName; ?>,ajaxOrigin:<?php echo $nonce; ?>},
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(res){
      console.log(res);
      }
    })
  });
});
</script>
```

** Code to keep in Functions **

```
<?php
function myAjaxHanlder()
{
  if(isset($_POST['ajaxOrigin']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['ajaxOrigin'], 'callMyAjax')){
    if(isset($_POST['li_id'])){
      $test = $_POST['li_id'];
      echo $test;
    }
  }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_callMyAjax', 'myAjaxHanlder' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_callMyAjax', 'myAjaxHanlder' );
?>
```

Comment: Do I add this to the top of my template.php file or to a separate .js file? If I need this in a separate .js file, how do I tell the template.php file to use the .js file?

Comment: i am updating my answer please look into that...

Comment: I have updated the script with your update and added some php code to echo the variable passed with the POST method (above in your answer). Now when I click the menu links it reloads the page but I am on seeing the value echo confirming php has the value.

Comment: change # with `javascript:void(0);` it will stop page to reload 

OR you can try to event handler in the same script:::

`jQuery('.dayLink a').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault;
.....`

Comment: Okay great, this prevents the page from reloading, but I am still not seeing the php value echoed by my test script.

Comment: this will give you value in json...check console of you browser..

Comment: console shows "net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" on my php file; https://grat-itudefitness/wp-content/themes/divi-child-gratitudefitness/single-b2p_program.php

Comment: Check i made some updates

Comment: Now when I click menu links I get   Uncaught ReferenceError: call_to_ajax is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> ((index):277)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery.js:3)

Comment: I made a few minor changes and got it to work. Thanks!

Comment: @david Mention not  :)